# Difference between Think time and Pacing Time in Performace testing

Tags: performance-testing

Pacing is used to achieve X number of iterations in X minutes, But I'm able to achieve x number of iterations in X minutes or x hours or x seconds by specifying only think time without using pacing time.

I want to know the actual difference between think time and pacing time? pacing time is necessary to mention between iterations? what this pacing time does?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions and your question is about concepts of testing, not programming. The question might be closed as being off topic. Please read the help pages (linked at the top of every Stackoverflow page) about what sort of questions can be asked. This question might be more suitable if asked on http://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, see sqa.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think time is a delay added after iteration is complete and before the next one is started. The iteration request rate depends on the sum of the response time and the think time. Because the response time can vary depending on a load level, iteration request rate will vary as well.

For constant request rate, you need to use pacing. Unlike think time,  pacing  adds a dynamically determined delay to keep iteration request rate constant while the response time can change.

For example, to achieve 3 iteration in 2 minutes, pacing time should be 2 x 60 / 3 = 40 seconds.  Here's an example how to use pacing in our tool http://support.stresstimulus.com/display/doc46/Delay+after+the+Test+Case

Answer (score 0):

Think Time
it introduces an element of realism into the test execution.
With think time removed, as is often the case in stress testing, execution speed and throughput can increase tenfold, rapidly bringing an application infrastructure that can comfortably deal with a thousand real users to its knees. 
always include think time in a load test.
think time influences the rate of transaction execution

Pacing
another way of affecting the execution of a performance test
affects transaction throughput