# Jmeter - Dummy Sampler vs Flow Action

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have read the user guide, here or on Blazemeter blogs regarding usage of flow action to implement dynamic pacing in Jmeter script with help of a JSR223 timer. I wanted to check if I can use JMX dummy sampler to implement the same JSR223 timer?

Does it really impact performance if using Dummy Sampler vs Flow Action in performance test scripts as both are samplers only. Please advise and any support link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impact performance of what?

["Pacing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207088/difference-between-think-time-and-pacing-time-in-performace-testing) is yet another approach to control the number of hits per second by slowing down the requests for whatever reason (not to overwhelm the application, send desired number of requests per second, etc.)

Any implementation of "pacing" is "killer" of the performance because it adds a **pause** between iterations instead of starting new iteration immediately so your question doesn't make a lot of sense. If you want to use the most resource efficient solution - you need to either share your implementation details for these 3 approaches or better measure it yourself using a [profiler tool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers)

If you're looking for a easier/better way of sending requests at constant rate instead of implementing the "pacing" I would rather recommend considering using of the following test elements:

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. My question was - can we use dummy samplers instead of flow action in a real high tps test and what difference of memory/cpu utilization that could bring. I believe you are asking to measure via any profiling tool.